# Arrows drawn with \foreach point to wrong side of \node

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, arrows, nodes, foreach

I noticed that arrows in the below MWE point to the wrong side of the nodes if I draw them with a `foreach` statement, but not if I write the same drawing command manually. What is wrong?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\node[draw, thick, circle, minimum size=7mm] (xA0) at (0, 0) {};
\foreach \i in {1, ..., 3}{
  \node[draw, thick, circle, minimum size=7mm] (xA\i) at (\i, 0) {};
  \node[draw, thick, circle, minimum size=7mm] (xB\i) at (\i, -1) {};
}
\node[draw, thick, circle, minimum size=7mm] (xB4) at (4, -1) {};
\foreach \i in {0, ..., 3}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\iplusone{\i+1};
  \draw[thick, -latex] (xA\i) -- (xB\iplusone);
  \ifnum\i<3
    \draw[thick, -latex] (xA\i) -- (xA\iplusone);
  \fi
  \ifnum\i>0
    \draw[thick, -latex] (xB\i) -- (xB\iplusone);
  \fi
}
\draw[thick, -latex, red] (xA0) -- (xB1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The goal is that the arrows point to closest end of the node without any manual computation where that point would be; just like the red arrow.

[image]

Comment: The reason is `\pgfmathsetmacro\iplusone{\i+1}`, which produces macros like `2.0`, where `.0` is interpreted as node anchor (the east anchor in this case). Instead of e.g. `\draw[thick, -latex] (xA\i) -- (xB\iplusone);` you can write `\draw[thick, -latex] (xA\i) -- (xB\the\numexpr\i+1);` or you could use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\iplusone{\i+1}`.

Comment: Thank you. Very insightful.

Comment: Well, I tried to give a detailed answer in which things get explained and the red arrow stays red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining additional counter in the loops: `[count=\j from 2]` you can omit calculation of node positions with `\pgfmathsetmacro`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4,
  C/.style = {draw, thick, circle, minimum size=7mm},
arr/.style = {thick, -latex}
                        ]
]
\foreach \i [count=\j from 2] in {1,...,4}
{
  \node[C] (xA\i) at (\i, 0) {};
  \node[C] (xB\i) at (\j, -1) {};
\draw[arr] (xA\i) -- (xB\i);
}
\foreach  \i [count=\j from 2] in {1,2,3}
{
\draw[arr] (xA\i) -- (xA\j);
\draw[arr] (xB\i) -- (xB\j);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! The reason is `\pgfmathsetmacro\iplusone{\i+1}`, which produces macros like `2.0`, where `.0` is interpreted as node anchor (the east anchor in this case).  There are many ways to fix this, either adding `int` to `\pgfmathsetmacro`, or to use  `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`, or with `\the\numexpr` as e.g. in

```
 \draw[thick, -latex] (xA\i) -- (xB\the\numexpr\i+1);
```

or with the evaluate key using `int`. This loop avoids overpainting one arrow. Here is a code that illustrates this, a much shorter and more ergonomic code can be found below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some foreach loop}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\node[draw, thick, circle, minimum size=7mm] (xA0) at (0, 0) {};
\foreach \i in {1, ..., 3}{
  \node[draw, thick, circle, minimum size=7mm] (xA\i) at (\i, 0) {};
  \node[draw, thick, circle, minimum size=7mm] (xB\i) at (\i, -1) {};
}
\node[draw, thick, circle, minimum size=7mm] (xB4) at (4, -1) {};
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using {int(\i+1)}]in {0,...,3}{
  \ifnum\i<3
    \draw[thick, -latex] (xA\i) -- (xA\j);
  \fi
  \ifnum\i>0
    \draw[thick, -latex] (xB\i) -- (xB\j);
    \draw[thick, -latex] (xA\i) -- (xB\j);
  \else 
    \draw[thick, -latex, red] (xA0) -- (xB1);
  \fi
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The above is to explain why things happen. You do not need any of this to draw the diagram, one single loop is enough.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\path[nodes={draw, thick, circle, minimum size=7mm},
    every edge/.append style={thick, -latex}] 
 foreach \i in {0, ..., 3}{
  (\i, 0) node[] (xA\i)  {}
  (\i+1, -1) node[] (xB\i)   {}
  \ifnum\i>0
   (xA\i) edge (xB\i)
  \else
   (xA\i) edge[red] (xB\i)
  \fi
  \ifnum\i>0
   (xA\the\numexpr\i-1) edge (xA\i)
   (xB\the\numexpr\i-1) edge (xB\i)
  \fi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]